# The difference between luma theme and blank

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, custom-theme

I often get asked which theme is the best to set as the parent, Blank or Luma, when it comes to creating a custom theme in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

One point I want to share: In theme blank, if you want to use some Widget like dropdown, you have to style or add style of theme lume into your theme while js function still work 
You will get this in theme blank
[image]

In theme lume 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is not much difference except a few UI appearances on the Listing page, product detail page, cart page, checkout page.

A very good description has been provided by the BSS theme. [Click here](https://bssthemes.com/blog/magento-2-theme-comparison-luma-and-blank/)